# Prove a function is onto given some conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose there is a $f:A\to B$ onto and $g: A\to B$ that is 1-1. Show that $g:A\to B$ is onto, or give a counterexample.

I think this seems true in the finite case, but when we deal with infinite sets it is no longer the case. Anyone know how to prove it for finite case? For infinite case, does $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}, n \to n$ and $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}, n \to n+1$ suffice as a counterexample?

Comment: You're exactly right. It's true in the finite case, and your counterexample is correct.

Comment: Are you sure you have written the statement correctly? What does $f$ have to do with all this?

Comment: $f$ gives some information of the size of $A$ and $B$ I think

Comment: Um... there must be a mistake in the question as the $f$ is irrelevant.  Just have $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be anything. (Why not the identity: $f(x) = x$). And let $g$ but 1-1 but not onto.  Say $f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$  then.... $f(x)$ is one to one but not onto.

Comment: "f gives some information of the size of A and B I think"  Oh, you are right.  $f$ and $g$ existance implies $|A| =|B|$.  For finite sets of equal cardinality then all one to one functions are onto. But not true if sets are infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are finite you can make a counting argument. Since $f$ is a surjective function from $A$ to $B$, for each $b\in B$ there is an element $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$, but since $A$ is not necessarily injective, $f^{-1}(b)$ (the preimage of $b$ under $f$, or the set of $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$) could be a set with several elements. Then $\lvert B\rvert \leq \lvert A \rvert$.

Now since $g$ is an injective function from $A$ to $B$, for each $b\in g(A)$ there is a *unique* $a \in A$ such that $g(a)=b$ (note $g(A)$ is not necessarily equal to $B$ yet, that's what we want to show). This shows $\lvert A\rvert \leq \lvert B \rvert$

Combining the above results notice that $\lvert A\rvert = \lvert B \rvert$

Since $g$ is injective $\lvert g(A) \rvert =\lvert A\rvert =\lvert B \rvert$. Since $B$ is finite and $g(A)\subset B$ with $\lvert g(A) \rvert =\lvert B \rvert$, it must be the case that  $g(A)=B$. This shows that $g$ is surjective as we wanted.